# Scala: Create xml programatically using callbacks?

Tags: xml, scala, tree

I have a library that runs through a tree structure using callbacks into a class.
A simplified variant is:

```
class CallBack {
    openGroup(name:String)
    closeGroup(name:String)
    item(name:String)
}
```

openGroup thus steps one step into the tree, closeGroup steps out and item are leafs.
What I would like to to is to create a simple xml structure 
as I run through the code. A naive solution would be to simply
do something like the below pseudocode:

```
class CallBack {
    var xml:String = ""
    openGroup(name:String)  = { xml += "<ol label=" + name + ">"}
    closeGroup(name:String) = { xml += "</ol>" }
    item(name:String)       = { xml += "<li name=.... />" }
}
```

I guess a nicer solution would be to create this using Node:s, Groups etc.,
or other relevant technique and then create the xml.

Do you have any idea how to create xml from the above in some decent manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [JATL](http://code.google.com/p/jatl), it would look something like

```
class CallBack(writer: Writer) {
    private val html = new Html(writer)
    def openGroup(name:String) = html.ol.label(name)
    def closeGroup(name:String) = html.end
    def item(name:String) = html.li.label(name).end
}
```

Comment: JATL looks cool, hadn't seen it before. But the actual problem with your code, if i read it correctly, is the same as if I would have used NodeSeq/... in regular scala: It doesn't handle the recursive nature in a good/easy way.

Consider the follwing call sequence:

openGroup("1") item("1.item1") openGroup("2") item("1.2.item2") closeGroup("2") closeGroup("1")

I guess your JATL solution wont cope with that?

Comment: @BjornJ Why wouldn't it? It will produce a nice nested list. Or do you want some different behavior? As given, it will not throw an exception if you do something illformed like `openGroup("1"); item("1.item1"); closeGroup("2")`, but it's easy enough to fix (just add a `Stack` keeping track of opened groups).

Comment: Yes, it does, sorry, I misunderstood how the library worked!
Thanks for your clarification!